# Can you 'loop' 2 loops in a single while statement from different tables?

Tags: php

I am trying to loop 2 different tables from the same database and displaying it at the same time. My question is, can you loop 2 different rows in a single while statement?

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT remaining from budget";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
$sql2 = "SELECT SUM(cost) as costTotal from project";   
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) && $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){?>

<span id='remain'><?php echo "$row2[costTotal]"; ?></span>
<span id='text'> <?php echo "$row[remaining]"; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: i tried it but it only looped 1 of the loops

Comment: in my project, im trying to display the ' total budget ' and the  ' total costs ' of a project

ex.

150 out of 1000 dollars used

Comment: You could probably do a join on the SQL statement.   If they have a relation between them use left or inner join would do the trick.
Then in this case, your budget and project should have a relation.

Comment: i gave up and just did 2 while statements, thanks anyway

Comment: What is the relationship of these tables?